# Is mcelog redundant if I'm using OpenManage as well?

Tags: linux, dell, snmp, dell-openmanage

I'm exploring whether it's worth deploying mcelog on physical RHEL machines. These machines are about 90% Dell and so we can see them in OpenManage and OM is configured to send alerts for various hardware error events, and I'm wondering how much overlap there would be with these two. We're not able to get much from Dell and I'm not able to find anything with my google-fu so I thought I'd check here.

Is OpenManage essentially going to check MCE events for me already or does it have another avenue it takes to get its information?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Open manage, Then there is no need to enable mce in the system. Because both doing the same thing.

Comment: Actually I verified with Dell Pre-Sales about a month after I posted this that MCE events (which aren't enabled or disabled) aren't recorded by OpenManage.